# How to serialize on SQL server metadata?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency

I tried to find an answer in Kalen Delaney's SQL Server Concurrency but there is no mention of metadata.

The problem is how to ensure that only one of these reads and index creates executes from one connection before the other connection does the same .

```
if not exists (select * from sysindexes with (XLOCK) where name = 'IND_audittrail_date_time') 
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IND_audittrail_date_time ON audittrail(date_time)
```

-- because we get

> java.sql.SQLException: The operation failed because an index or
>   statistics with name 'IND_audittrail_date_time' already exists on
>   table 'audittrail'.

Query:

```
if not exists (select * from sysindexes with (XLOCK) where name = 'IND_audittrail_date_time')
```

Reading [Metadata Access, Isolation Levels, and Lock Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175065.aspx)
I found this

> SQL Server does not guarantee that lock hints will be honored in
>   queries that access metadata through catalog views, compatibility
>   views, information schema views, metadata-emitting built-in functions

Is there an accepted way how this is done? Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, `sys.sysindexes` is deprecated. You should be using `sys.indexes` if you are on 2008+.

Comment: Metadata access is always read committed, irrelevant of you hints, transaction isolation level or DB snapshot settings.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you cant serialize this in the application code you can use try/catch or an applock

```
begin tran
if APPLOCK_TEST ('public','idx_create','exclusive') = 1
 begin 
  EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'idx_create', 
                     @lockmode = 'Exclusive', 
                     @DbPrincipal='public'
   print 'I can do it'

  -- EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource='idx_create', @DbPrincipal='public'
  -- scope is transaction see comment below
   commit 
 end
else rollback ;
```

Comment: +1 but loose the `sp_releaseapplock`. Since the scope/owner is `Transaction` the lock will be released at commit time. Is a bad idea to release X locks early, violation of [two-phase locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) *will* come back and bite you.

Comment: Correct - I'll update :)

Comment: Thank you. I did a quick test with SQLQueryStress and it seems to work. I also put sys.indexes.